# jquery on change only first once with delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've looked for an answer to this, but all the questions I could find tell me to use delegation which I have done as seen below, but yet it still only fires once when I select an item from a dropdown.

My HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="CatalogItems" name="CatalogItems">
<option value="value one">Keyboard Trays</option>
<option value="value two">Another option</option>
```

Pretty simple.  My javascript code is:

```
$(document).on("change", "#CatalogItems", function() {
    console.log("The item has been changed...");
});
```

This HTML is generated by a partial form when I select another item from another dropdown.  I have that working just fine, so not including that code.  This code works only once when I select the first item.  When I use the other dropdown to reload the partial view that creates this CatalogItems dropdown, the above on change code will work again only once.  So it seems to be attached correctly for persisting through Ajax calls, but I'm not sure why it is only firing once.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So to make things a bit clearer:  If my Ajax call only happens at the beginning of the page load, which loads in the above dropdown I only am able to get my script as above to fire off once.  If I do not do any more Ajax calls, it still fires off once.  When I inspect the element of the dropdown list, nothing there changes (as far as ids, classes, etc) when I select an item.  There's not duplicates as I haven't fired off the Ajax call to replace the partial.  I'd supply more code, but that's really all I have for this bit on functionality.

Comment: It should work (not only once, that is), so I guess it's related to some other part of your code. Can you try to reproduce the issue on a JSFiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it could be that when the code you generate is reloaded the second time, you have not removed the original code from the DOM, resulting in two elements with the same id on the page. If the code is regenerated, you need to make sure that the first set of elements is "removed", for example:

```
$("#some-id").html().remove();
```

Any html subsequently added will be unique, with unique ids. More code is needed in the question to be more sure about this though.

Comment: I actually didn't consider that, so I placed in some code in the function that does the Ajax call.  Unfortunately that's not the issue as it is occurring after only the initial load which means the original partial view is never replaced.  However, it still only fires off once.

Comment: Yeah that's caught me out before now. You really need to show some more code in your question to consider this properly, otherwise it's just guessing at what might be wrong. Partials can sometimes be tricky with scripts and a lot will depend on how everything loads and behaves.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I need to use Chrome more often for its dev tools.  I've been using Firefox.  Since my event was the same string, I forgot that it doesn't show for multiple occurrences.  In FF however, the indicator is WAY over to the right and is small so it's easy to miss (and my right eye is garbage which doesn't help).  Once I dl'd Chrome on the vm I'm working on and fired it up, it was obvious because the indicator is RIGHT THERE next to the string right up front.  So it's been working fine, I'm just blind and forgetful.